# Вытащить пользователя по id из url

Tags: php, mysql

Есть раздел вида site.ru/u/ нужно доставать пользователей по типу site.ru/**u/evgenii/**

**как можно вытащить "evgenii"** из этого урла чтобы дальше делать выборку по бд пользователей с этим логином. при этом это не гет и не пост запрос. Есть какие-нибудь идеи? спасибо!

Comment: Вытащить нужно на клиентской стороне или серверной?

Comment: Не гет и не пост? Отчего не скажете точно, что за метод? И, зачем вообще ходите такими нестандартными тропами?

Comment: Как у Мольера господин Журден не подозревал, что говорит прозой, так и здесь автор просто не догадывается, что использует метод GET :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Все данные можно получить в php по `parse_url` вам поможет почитать можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)

Если требуется объяснения то вот:

```
  <?php
    $url = 'site.ru/u/evgenii/';
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $path_array = explode('/', $path);
    print_r($path_array); // Можно удалить
    echo $path_array[2]; // Можно удалить
    $user_name = $path_array[2];
  ?>
```

[Посмотреть в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f2b068f159326f6628daeb66c795f1858da81c29)